# How to sort a list of time values?

Tags: python, list, sorting, time

I have a python list of time values that I extracted from a web log. I have the list in the format of `%H:%M:%S`.  How would I sort the time values in ascending order?

Answer (score 11):

Just `sorted(time_list)` works fine.

```
>>> sorted(["14:10:01", "03:12:08"])
["03:12:08", "14:10:01"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import time

sorted((time.strptime(d, "%H:%M:%S") for d in time_list), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted([tuple(map(int, d.split(":"))) for d in my_time_list])
```

Where each element in my_time_list is of the form you describe, for example:

```
>>> my_time_list
["03:12:08", "14:10:01"]
```

Comment: it returns [[3, 12, 8], [14, 10, 1]]. Data type of elements in returned list is different from the input list, which may not be what he whats.

Comment: I often cast time units to ints because 1) You get type checking and 2) It allows easier interoperability with the datatime module types

Comment: You can also do this with the `key` argument to not change the values: `sorted(my_time_list, key=lambda d: tuple(map(int, d.split(":"))))`

Answer (score 0):

you should be able use the method `sort(key=str.lower)` since your time is parsed as a string