# regex for detecting subtitle errors

Tags: regex

I'm having some issues with subtitles, I need a way to detect specific errors. I think regular expressions would help but need help figuring this one out. In this example of SRT formatted subtitle, line #13 ends at 00:01:10,130 and line #14 begins at 00:01:10:129.

```
13
00:01:05,549 --> 00:01:10,130
some text here.

14
00:01:10,129 --> 00:01:14,109
some other text here.
```

Problem is that next line can't begin before current one is over - embedding algorithm doesn't work when that happens. I need to check my SRT files and correct this manually, but looking for this manually in about 20 videos each an hour long just isn't an option. Specially since I need it 'yesterday' (:

Format for SRT subtitles is very specific:

```
XX 
START --> END 
TEXT
EMPTY LINE

[line number (digits)][new line character]
[start and end times in 00:00:00,000 format, separated by _space__minusSign__minusSign__greaterThenSign__space_][new line character]
[text - can be any character - letter, digit, punctuation sign.. pretty much anything][new line character]
[new line character]
```

I need to check if END time is greater then START time of the following subtitle. Help would be appreciated.

PS. I can work with Notepad++, Eclipse (Aptana), python or javascript...

Comment: How have you attempted to solve that problem? What is it you are actually asking us for?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions *can* be used to achieve what you want, that being said, they **can't** do it on their own. Regular expressions are used for matching patterns and not numerical ranges.

If I where you, what I would do would be as following:

1. Parse the file and place the start-end time in one data structure (call it `DS_A`) and the text in another (call it `DS_B`).
2. Sort `DS_A` in ascending order. This should guarantee that you will not have overlapping ranges. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713873/how-do-i-sort-a-python-list-of-time-values) previous SO post should point you in the right direction).
3. Iterate over and write the following in your file:`j DS_A[i] --> DS_A[i + 1] <newline> DS_B[j]` where `i` is a loop counter for `DS_A` and `j` is a loop counter for `DS_B`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing short script to fix this. here it is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime
import getopt, re, sys

count = 0
def fix_srt(inputfile):
  global count
  parsed_file, errors_file = '', ''
  try:
    with open( inputfile , 'r') as f:
      srt_file = f.read()
      parsed_file, errors_file = parse_srt(srt_file)
  except:
    pass
  finally:
    outputfile1 = ''.join( inputfile.split('.')[:-1] ) + '_fixed.srt'
    outputfile2 = ''.join( inputfile.split('.')[:-1] ) + '_error.srt'
    with open( outputfile1 , 'w') as f:
      f.write(parsed_file)
    with open( outputfile2 , 'w') as f:
      f.write(errors_file)
    print 'Detected %s errors in "%s". Fixed file saved as "%s"
           (Errors only as "%s").' % ( count, inputfile, outputfile1, outputfile2 )

previous_end_time = datetime.strptime("00:00:00,000", "%H:%M:%S,%f")
def parse_times(times):
  global previous_end_time
  global count
  _error = False
  _times = []
  for time_code in times:
    t = datetime.strptime(time_code, "%H:%M:%S,%f")
    _times.append(t)

  if _times[0] < previous_end_time:
    _times[0] = previous_end_time
    count += 1
    _error = True
  previous_end_time = _times[1]

  _times[0] =  _times[0].strftime("%H:%M:%S,%f")[:12]
  _times[1] = _times[1].strftime("%H:%M:%S,%f")[:12]

  return _times, _error

def parse_srt(srt_file):
  parsed_srt = []
  parsed_err = []
  for srt_group in re.sub('\r\n', '\n', srt_file).split('\n\n'):
    lines = srt_group.split('\n')
    if len(lines) >= 3:
      times = lines[1].split(' --> ')
    correct_times, error = parse_times(times)
    if error:
      clean_text = map( lambda x: x.strip(' '), lines[2:] )
      srt_group = lines[0].strip(' ') + '\n' + ' --> '.join( correct_times ) + '\n' + '\n'.join( clean_text )
      parsed_err.append( srt_group )
    parsed_srt.append( srt_group )
  return '\r\n'.join( parsed_srt ), '\r\n'.join( parsed_err )

def main(argv):
  inputfile = None
  try:
    options, arguments = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:", ["input="])
  except:
    print 'Usage: test.py -i <input file>'

  for o, a in options:
    if o == '-h':
      print 'Usage: test.py -i <input file>'
      sys.exit()
    elif o in ['-i', '--input']:
      inputfile = a
  fix_srt(inputfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main( sys.argv[1:] )
```

If someone needs it save the code as srtfix.py, for example, and use it from command line:

```
python srtfix.py -i "my srt subtitle.srt"
```

I was lazy and used datetime module to process timecodes, so not sure script will work for subtitles longer then 24h (: I'm also not sure when miliseconds were added to Python's datetime module, I'm using version 2.7.5; it's possible script won't work on earlier versions because of this...